# Matching large character variables using filter

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I collected data with multiple ID numbers with letters, there are matching id numbers in both data frames. I wanted to match these Id number by using filter. I extracted the id numbers from one data frame n=1850 as list or a data frame of 500n to filter them out and using filter to match each one.

Example:

| df1 |
| --- |
| AXD125 |
| AZD122 |
| AYD123 |

#Goes to 1800.. rows and it contains 5 variables but I wanna filter by ID number

and

I have a list of dfx <- c("AZD125", "AYD124", "AWZ321"........ #goes to 500)

I was trying to use dfx with filter manually to filter the specific Ids from dfx Like that

dfx %>% filter (ID == "AXD125")

But I have 500 ids to type. Is there an easier easy to do it?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible minimal dataset. Also, consider merging rather than filtering.

Comment: @Maël hope that helped

Comment: @Maël it did thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, this is the best guess I can give you

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
  ID = c("AZD125", "AYD124", "AWZ321", "BVB09"),
  val = c(1:4)
)

dfx <- tibble(
  ID = c("AZD125","NA", "AWZ321", "NA", "SCP", "Error"),
               val2 = c(1:6)
)

df %>% left_join(dfx, by ="ID")
```